# Parsing angular-cli.json failed. Syntax error at position 0

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Hello I have researched this issue and have implemented two solutions that worked for others but I am still getting the same error. I am walking through this tutorial here:

https://devblog.dymel.pl/2016/10/25/angular2-cli-with-aspnet-core-application-tutorial/

However when running npm start in the Frontend directory I receive an error that reads

**Parsing angular-cli.json failed. Please make your angular-cli.json is valid.
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ? at position 0.**

I have tried the solution here:

[Parsing angular-cli.json failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42469904/parsing-angular-cli-json-failed)

by building a new project with angular-cli, pasting the angular-cli.json file from new project while changing the name and OutDir. Then I went to tools -- options -- text editor -- general -- and unchecked "AutoDetect UTF 8 encoding without signature".

However I still get the same error. This is really frustrating.

angular-cli.json

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "project": {
    "name": "MYPROJ"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "../Backend/wwwroot",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
      "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "styles": [
        "styles.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [],
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
  "e2e": {
    "protractor": {
      "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "lint": [
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.app.json"
    },
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
    },
    {
      "project": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json"
    }
  ],
  "test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": "./karma.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "css",
    "component": {}
  }
}
```

Comment: I've gotten this when VS encodes it using UTF-BOM-8. If you have Notepad++, try to open it in there, and in the encoding menu set it to just plain UTF-8

Comment: @Steveadoo Ok im going to try it now. One moment......

Comment: Unfortunately it did not work. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Could you upload your file somewhere? Instead of just pasting the contents?

Comment: Absolutely! can I upload here? Else I will push to github

Comment: https://github.com/RyeGuy12/Steveadoo2       Unfortunately even github cannot open the class library (Frontend) where angular-cli.json lives. So the file did not upload

Comment: Maybe you can just open the file in a hex editor (there are even online editors) and see what bytes are at the beginning. As Steveadoo pointed out, you could try to change your editor encoding so it doesn't write byte order mark (BOM) to the beginning of the file.

Comment: Ok ill try that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this problem I had to restart the tutorial from the beginning. But ***before*** doing so I had to go to:

Tools | Options | Text Editor | General: then uncheck **Auto-detect UTF-8 encoding without signature** and **Follow project coding conventions.**

Then begin the tutorial and everything should work. No amount of deleting and re-adding the angular-cli.json file or changing the text editor settings or making sure the file was not using UTF-BOM would work. In my experience, if you receive this error you *must* start from the beginning *after* adjusting the settings